# Clear bash history except last n lines

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

I have following command to clear last entry of bash history(terminal history/command-line history). My Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

```
sed -i '$d' ~/.bash_history
```

But I want to keep last `1,2...n` entries and delete the rest, how can I achieve that ?

Can be with `sed`/`history`/`awk` or any other command, no problem as far as the requirements are met.

Comment: `sed -i '1,10!d' ~/.bash_history` replace 10 with whatever you want to count up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the last N lines, use `tail` (for example, the last 20 lines):

```
tail -n 20 "$HISTFILE" > ff && mv ff "$HISTFILE"
```

I'm using the `HISTFILE` variable since this will always point to your history file, even if you've changed its name.

Comment: But when I run your command, I get error `cannot open ‘/home/<user>/.bash_history’ for reading: No such file or directory`. Why so ? `echo "$HISTFILE"` gives `/home/user/.bash_history` so path is correct. Also can this same thing be done with `sed` command ?

Comment: @VickyDev what do you get for `ls -l "$HISTFILE"`? It sounds like you don't have one. As for `sed`, no, not really. AFAIK there's no way for `sed` to count from the end of the file. You could reverse the file, take the top few lines and reverse it again (`tac "$HISTFILE" | sed -n '1,10p' | tac > ff && mv ff "$HISTFILE"` but that seems way too complicated.

Comment: As I said the path and vatiable are correct, also I get `-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Oct  4 10:44 /home/ubuntu/.bash_history` for `ls -l $HISTFILE` but that doesn't work with `tail` command you gave in asnwer. It says `/home/ubuntu/.bash_history’ for reading: No such file or directory`. Oh didn't know `tac`(reverse of `cat`) was also there, thanks for that.

Comment: @VickyDev that doesn't really make sense. The error you show means that the file doesn't exist. However, your `ls` shows the file does exist (but is empty). Something very strange is going on here. Come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and ping me if you want to debug it further.